Age Calculator (JavaScript) giving the wrong age by +1 year
This is the code I used, the HTML is 3 input types to record the dd/mm/yyyy the user has put in. When putting in my own birthday it gives me the age a year older than I am. This is the same if I do different years also.
I tried doing month - 1 as I know JS handles month a little differently but that didn't seem to fix it
function calculateAge() {

    // Input Values + (converts to number)
    const day = +document.getElementById('day-input').value;
    const month = +document.getElementById('month-input').value;
    const year = +document.getElementById('year-input').value;

    // Sets the new Date input (-1 month to match real months)
    const birthDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    console.log(birthDate)

    // sets the new date to today const/get date
    const today = Date.now()

    const diff = today - birthDate.getTime();

    // subtracts age from birth year and current year
    let age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();

    // month  - birth month
    const monthDiff = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();

    document.getElementById('result-box').innerText = `Your age is: ${age}`;
}


You compute the month difference but do nothing with the resulting value.

Are there any errors in your console? TypeError: today.getFullYear is not a function"

What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? That's so little code that debugging it should not be that hard

This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Once you figure out what to do with the month difference, you'll want to do the same thing with the day-of-month.

How about using a date picker instead of three inputs? Easier to use, looks great, and has full support.

Why are you randomly using const vs let?  Const should not be used for computed values.

@JohnLord "Const should not be used for computed values." Huh? Sure it should. It should be used for any variable that won't be reassigned.

Please provide the HTML along with the JavaScript in a Stack Snippet so that people have a [mre] to work with.

do what you want but you'll regret it someday when you use that function in a partial view.  Hoisting will flip it to the main view and the next time you load the partial view (usually in a popup), the js will crash (unless it's in a function).  Just because you can do something in js doesn't mean you should.  You're only getting away with it because js is interpreted.  That isn't allowed in compiled languages and for good reason.

The origin of the error is this: the variable "today" is not a date object; rather, it is a timestamp. The "Date.now()" call returns the timestamp of the current date in milliseconds. Therefore, "today" is not a date object but a timestamp.
In this case, to calculate the age difference, you should take the difference between "Date.now()" and "birthDate.getTime()". This can be achieved by subtracting the timestamp of the birth date from the current timestamp. Then, you can use this difference to calculate the age.
Understanding that the issue is resolved in its simplest form.
const today = new Date(Date.now());

